# Angular Cannot Find Name Buffer

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I keep getting this error when trying to use Jimp to execute the code bellow. I read around the issues and found that there were issues with buffer in version .28. I downgraded to .27 and this didn't help. I was wondering if this was still an issue or if I incorrectly imported the files.

```
ERROR in node_modules/jimp/jimp.d.ts(18,24): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Buffer'.
```

I think this may be an error with the .d.ts file because I'm not using buffer in the code.

I have imported the type for Jimp into my dev dependencies (npm i --save-dev @types/node), but the new version of Jimp says it doesnt need these types it has its own. I have also put "types":["node"] into my tsconfig.json file.

Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as jimp from 'jimp';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jimp-test',
  templateUrl: './jimp-test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jimp-test.component.css']
})
export class JimpTestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.testJimp();
  }

  testJimp() {
    jimp.read('assets/testInput.jpg').then( (img) => {
      img.clone().blur(1).write('assets/testOutput.jpg');
    });
  }

}
```

Dependencies

```
{
  "name": "my-playground",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jimp": "^0.2.28",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jimp": "^0.2.28",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Angular Versions

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Jimp Version

```
0.2.28
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

This line should be on top:

```
declare const Buffer
```

and it should compile without errors.

With new version of Typescript, you can also use official declaration files:

```
npm i -g typescript@next
npm i --save-dev @types/node
```

and add `"types" : ["node"]` in `tsconfig.app.json` file.

Comment: I tried this once. It didnt work I tried it again and it still didnt work

Comment: please share you 'tsconfig.json' and ;tsconfig.app.json

Comment: Posted both in the main post

Comment: Please add  "types" :  ["node"] in tsconfig.app.json

Comment: I did this error was fixed. Now I have different errors. Thanks!

Comment: I have 2 ng apps, the first does not need  "types" : ["node"] in tsconfig.app.json, but the 2nd needs. Both use a component that triggers the error. Anyway, adding the line had resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if can help anybody but I solved it by adding:

`import {Utils} from 'tslint'`

into my component. Crazy it worked

Comment: This allowed the function to compile - though it's not called - but it failed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please add "types" : ["node"] in **tsconfig.app.json**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).